# PHP Pagination result increased on each page

Tags: php, sql, pagination

I am a newbie in php.

I am creating a Lister site containing `id`, `name` and `url`, I am trying to create pagination with limit of 10 sites on each page.

Page 1 is fine with 10 sites, but when I go to page 2 the list increased to 20 sites started from 11-30.

On page 3 contain 30 sites started from 21-50. 
On page 4, 40 sites started from 31-70.

I want my site to list only 10 sites each page.

**Following is my code**

```
    <?php
    $r1 = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query('select count(id) as nb from mydb where status="on"'));

    if(isset($_GET['page']))
    {
    $page = intval($_GET["page"]);       
    }
    else
    {
    $page = 1;      
    }

    $nbpages = ceil($r1['nb']/$limit);
    if($page<1 or $page>$nbpages)
    {
    $page = 1;
    }
    $pages_site = ' ';
    if($page>1)
    {
    $pages_site .= '<a href="?page='.($page-1).'">Prev</a> ';
    }
    for($i=1;$i<=$nbpages;$i++)
    {
    if($i==$page)
    {
    $pages_site .= '<strong>'.$i.'</strong> ';
    }
    else
    {
    $pages_site .= '<a href="?page='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a> ';
    }
    }
    if($page<$nbpages)
    {
    $pages_site .= '<a href="?page='.($page+1).'">Next</a>';
    }
    ?>
    <div><?php echo $pages_site; ?></div>
    <?php
    $first_message = ($page-1)*$limit;
    $last_message = $first_message  +$limit;
    $i = $first_message ;

    $r2 = mysql_query('select id, name from mydb where status="on" order by id desc limit '.$first_message .','.$last_message);
    while($d2 = mysql_fetch_array($r2))
    {
    $i++;
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update `$last_message = $first_message  +$limit;` to `$last_message = $limit;`